# Bokeh: How can I directly access the colors in a ColorMapper?

Tags: python, bokeh

I use a `LinearColorMapper` in Bokeh 2.3.0 to map values to certain colors in my plot. Nothing fancy, as shown in the minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.layouts import layout

plot1 = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=250)

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
                   "Value1":[0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700], 
                   "Color": [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3] # Those somehow correspond to the categories, but will change during runtime
                  })
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

possible_categories = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

cmap = LinearColorMapper(palette="Turbo256", low = 0, high = len(possible_categories))
                        
circle = plot1.circle(x='ID', y='Value1', source=source, 
                      fill_color={"field":'Color', "transform":cmap}, 
                      line_color={"field":'Color', "transform":cmap})


layout_ = layout([[plot1]])
curdoc().add_root(layout_)
```

But I wonder if there is a possibility to 'manually' access the colors directly from the `cmap` that I created? I would like to pass a value to the cmap and get the color or Hex-Color-Code or something similar back. Somehow like this (which of course does not work, but illustrates the idea):

```
for categ, num in enumerate(possible_categories):

    color = cmap.get_colorcode_to_the_following_value(num)
    print(f"Color of Category {possible_categories[categ]}: {color}")
```

with the output:

```
Color of Category A: ColorCodeXXX
Color of Category B: ColorCodeXXX
Color of Category C: ColorCodeXXX
Color of Category D: ColorCodeXXX
```

I´m sure this somehow works, but I extensively looked up the reference of Bokeh and did not find anything like this.

Answer (score 3):

The color mapping done by `LinearColorMapper` is actually performed on the *JavaScript side, in the browser*. The information is never computed or available in Python. If you require this information, you would need to map and set the colors on the glyph manually, without using Bokeh's `LinearColorMapper`.

Comment: Thnaks for that information. When you say *map and set the colors on the glyph manually*, do you mean to have an extra column in my ColumnDataSource that holds the ColorValue for that individual sample with a chosen Value-to-color-mapping?

Comment: Yes, exactly. An extra column in the CDS with colors that you compute (so therefore have access to in Python).